# AVERAGEIFS parse error

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Sheet12!R:R,Sheet12!A:A,N5,Sheet12!B:B,">=9/16/2018",Sheet12!B:B,"<=10/3/2018")
```

While giving cell range instead of a date value, it's showing error.

Comment: next time pls share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Sheet12!R:R, Sheet12!A:A, N5,
                         Sheet12!B:B, ">="&DATE(2018, 9, 16),
                         Sheet12!B:B, "<="&DATE(2018, 10, 3))
```

[image: 6]

Comment: can we use cell reference instead of date.                                                                         for an example in place of  q:q,">="&Date(2018, 9, 16), can I write q:q,>=q1

Comment: @Gaurav yes you can: `=AVERAGEIFS(Sheet12!R:R, Sheet12!A:A, N5,
                         Sheet12!B:B, ">="&A1,
                         Sheet12!B:B, "<="&A2)`

Comment: while applying this formula, it's giving #ERROR!                                                                I am applying this formula in a google sheet

Comment: It's done....Thanks for your help